# How can i edit what values a http service returns using rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this http service which returns an object, like for example this:

```
{ 
entries: [..,..,..,..],
entries2: [..,..,..],
somevalue: "the value",
somemore: "another value"
}
```

I'm using Angular's HttpClient, with a http.get(url).

i am able to do this:

```
http.get(url).map(result=>result['entries'])
```

when i subscribe on that, i only get the "entries". But i would like to have both the "entries", and "entries2" returned when i subscribe. I just don't understand how to do that. I've googled, for a few hours now, but I'm not even sure what to google for. ;)

So if anyone see what I'm trying to do, and would like to at least put me on the right track, please let me know :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try `.map(result => ({entries: result.entries, entries2: result.entries2}));`. Bear in mind there is no need to use the square bracket syntax here, so I've just replaced it with dot notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
.map (result => ({ 
  entries: result.entries,
  entries2: result.entries2 
}))
```

`map` can return anything actually. You can "project" `result` to any object you want.

If you want to return one big array which is the concatenation of entries and entries2, you could do something like this, for instance :

```
.map(result => result.entries.concat(result.entries2));
```

)

Comment: You may want `({` insead of just `{`. Braces after the `=>` indicate function body, not object body.

Comment: Ah right, thank you ! I was just trying to run my first example, it wasn't working and I was temporarily going for the "return {}" version. Your suggestion is the way to go. edited.